# R program to calculate the mean of the results of the same experiments

Tags: r, mean

I am working R program that needs to take the mean values of all the results of the same experiment. For instance, there are two experiments, respectively experiment 1 and experiment 2. Experiment 1 has three results per row, and experiment 2 has two results per row. The program should calculate the mean results of experiment 1 and the mean results of experiment 2.

```
cols<-c('experiment 1 result 1','experiment 1 result 2','experiment 1 result 3','experiment 2 result 1','experiment 2 result 2') 
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 1)) 
colnames(df)<-cols 
df[1,]<-c(1,3,2,2,4)
```

In the case of the given example the output should be the following dataframe:

```
cols<-c('experiment 1','experiment 2') 
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 1)) 
colnames(df)<-cols 
df[1,]<-c(2,3)
```

Depend on the situation the number of experiments, and the number of results per experiment can vary. I am, therefore looking for a generic approach to solve this. Is there somebody who could help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only the "experiment" number from the column names :

```
sub(' result \\d+', '', names(df))
#[1] "experiment 1" "experiment 1" "experiment 1" "experiment 2" "experiment 2"
```

Use this as a grouping variable in `tapply` to get :

```
tapply(unlist(df), sub(' result \\d+', '', names(df)), mean)
#experiment 1 experiment 2 
#           2            3
```

---

For more than 1 row we can use `split.default` :

```
sapply(split.default(df, sub(' result \\d+', '', names(df))), rowMeans)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is already a very nice step. May i ask you an additional quesiton: How would solve it if you have multiple rows with experiments, so for instance, `df[2,]<-c(2,3,1,3,4)` ? Then i do get the error `arguments must have same length`

Comment: What would be expected output in that case? Do you need rowwise mean or total mean?

Comment: My apologies, i should have mentioned that. I would like to have a rowwise mean.

Comment: Updated the answer to use `split.default`.